# Heroku: to_datetime does not take into account the rails' i18n.locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, heroku, string-to-datetime

Edit: (to be clear and to the point)

I want the following to work on heroku: `"11/13/2011".to_datetime`, meaning I need the dates to be in english format. Thanks

---

I've set this the i18n locale in my `application.rb`

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.locale = :en
```

In the heroku console:

```
I18n.locale
=> :en
```

So it seems like it's set correctly.

But when I do:

```
"11/13/2011".to_datetime
=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Noooo!

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The i18n config had nothing to do with my problem.
Just a ruby version "problem".

I was working with ruby 1.8.7 in my local env, and heroku was at 1.9.x.

Rails 1.9 assumes EU format, 1.8.7 does not.